Draggable Container with a height: double.infinity
I am trying to do a container that will fill the height with the size of the screen.
        Container(
          color: Colors.yellow, //Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
          width: 200.0,
          height: double.infinity,
        ),

Also is possible using Flexible or Expanded...
But the problem is I wan to do this container draggable.
If I use a height: 200.0 for instance, work fine but, when I try to use these methods to get a container with the height as the same of the screen I always get errors.
We can fix it?
I am using Chrome to deploy but also Windows.
Thank you!
    Flexible(
      child: Draggable(
        feedback: Container(
          color: Colors.red, //Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
          width: 200.0,
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellow, //Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
          width: 200.0,
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    );

This will render the yellow container but when I try to drag it, errors are fired.
With this code works fine only if i keep the height in the feedback as fixed like 300.0.
     Flexible(
      child: Draggable(
        feedback: Container(
          color: Colors.red, //Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
          width: 200.0,
          height: 300.0//double.maxFinite,
        ),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellow, //Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
          width: 200.0,
          height: double.maxFinite,
        ),
      ),
    );


With or without draggable, it's not possible to have a dynamic height container while also wanting a fixed height container based on the size of the screen. Either way you would eventually need to make them scrollable because there are devices that are very small in height, causing everything to overflow
